# Multiplying the values of two different models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Well i'm trying to create two models whereas the product model is:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    price = models.FloatField(null=False)
    inStock = models.BooleanField(null=False)
```

and another model for cart where:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    productID = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    total
```

**I want total here to equal Product.price multiplied by the Cart.quantity**
Is there a way how can I achieve it on Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @property decorator

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    productID = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.quantity * self.productID.price
```

To use in serializer you can try this:

```
total = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_total(self, obj):
    return obj.total
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I get it to show in the Api,I only get [ { "id": 9, "quantity": 2, "product": 2 }]

Comment: are you using drf? and serializers?

Comment: Yes I am using serializers and drf

Comment: updated the awnser, add this to your serializer